# Custom error redirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-error-pages

I have been using Custom Error Redirect page in asp.net application. following is my web.config code

```
 <customErrors mode="On"
  defaultRedirect="DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Http404ErrorPage.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

`DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx` exist in root folder i.e `MyWebsite/DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx`
It works fine when exception occurred in page that is in root folder of application e.g `MyWebsite/Default.aspx`

But when exception occurred in page that not on root folder e.g `MyWebsite/UserControls/MyUserControl.ascx` , It fails saying

Could not find page `MyWebsite\UserControls\DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx`

What i am missing ?

Comment: can you set `defaultRedirect="/DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you specified for `defaultRedirect` and `redirect` is your page and asp.net will be looked in current directory of the page that caused error. You can use `~/` to start from root irrespective of the page path that caused the error.

```
<customErrors mode="On"
  defaultRedirect="~/DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Http404ErrorPage.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

**[defaultRedirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx)**

> The URL can be absolute (for example, www.contoso.com/ErrorPage.htm)
>   or relative. A relative URL, such as /ErrorPage.htm, is relative to
>   the Web.config file that specified the URL for this attribute, not to
>   the Web page in which the error occurred. A URL starting with a tilde
>   (~), such as ~/ErrorPage.htm, indicates that the specified URL is
>   relative to the root path of the application, MSDN.

Comment: I have tried `~/Http404ErrorPage.aspx"/` but same result

Comment: You need ~/ in both I guess you need defaultRedirect at the moment

Comment: Is your website restarted, try to restart IIS if you can, it should have worked.

Comment: Working now... Actually exception is raising in `callback`. SO i need to add another handler for this.. But logic remain same ie adding `~` Thanks :)